# How to have interface methods with a different number and type of parameters? C#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, computer-science-theory

Let's say I have multiple classes that all have the same actions (in my case I'm creating a plugin framework that all: Load, Run, Dispose), and I want to use an interface so I can create a PluginFactory to handle the initialization. The problem is they all need wildly different data so the methods would be the same but the parameters would be different. Is there a best practice or design pattern where I can use interfaces and polymorhism while passing in different data to the methods?

Generics wouldn't necessarily solve my problem because the number and types of parameters is different for each plugin. I'm thinking of creating a container inside the methods when I implement them that retrieves the parameters from a global source and therefore I can inject different dependencies into that global source when I test but I'm not sure if that breaks any abstraction rules.

Edit:

Here's a code example:

```
 public interface IPlugin
    {
        void Load();
    }

    public Hubbub : IPlugin
    {
        public void Load(int individualId, IApiDataSource apiDataSource)
        {
           //code
        }
    }

public class SysEx : IPlugin
{
    Load(OAuthToken token, string connString, User user)
    {
        //code
    }
}

public class FriendPlat: IPlugin
{
    Load(string username, string password)
    {    
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: If the parameters are different for each plugin, how does the plugin host know what parameters to pass to which plugin?

Comment: "I'm thinking of creating a container..." Good idea. So what´s your question?

Comment: @mjwills ok added an edit

Comment: @NineBerry yeah that's pretty much my question. Is there anything I can do or just give up interfaces all together or retrieve the data through a container loaded internally by each class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Is it a good idea? That's really my question. If this is the best way than I'll do it. So the interface methods wouldn't accept any parameters and each class would be responsible for looking at a container to get their data parameters?

Comment: @Eitan even with your code now its hard to tell what exactly this would solve.  Why have an interface at all?  Its not like you reference anything from the interface since you wouldn't have a class that implements a parameterless method

Comment: Are the arguments computational the expensive? You could simply include every parameter in the interface, and the method that implements the interfaces free to pick and choose what arguments to use and which ones to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface eg ILoadArgument

Create a class per IPlugin implementation eg FriendlyPlatArgument, SysExArgument etc. These dto classes can implement ILoadArgument interface that you created. May be they all need a common property eg CreatedAt that can also goto the interface.

Now your IPlugin interface can define Load method as

Void Load(ILoadArgument arg) ;

Also you can then make it generic as:

Void Load(T arg) where T:ILoadArgument{°°°}

Comment: ok that makes sense. Most the methods are the same but the load method needs different parameters and this solves it. Thanks!